# Spideroak no longer recognises my machine as a member of the account and wants a new setup

Tags: ubuntu, spideroak

I am running Ubuntu 16.04LTS, and changed a set of files and after rebooting, 'spideroak' (**https://spideroak.com/**) stopped recognizing my computer as being one of the registered and identified devices in my backup list. I login without a problem, but I am prompted to the `Account setup` screen, which asks me to enter a name for this `new computer`, and cannot let me click on the name of the listed devices it should be associated with.

Is my only solution to delete the listed device and start over on this machine as a new install?

Comment: @DavidPostill, from the link you gave me, can you tell me which point classifies this question as being 'off topic'? It is not a question asking a 'favourite', or anything 'subjective'. It is *practical*, and not 'open ended'. I am not asking for an 'intuitive explanation', and it is *reasonably scoped*. Whether it's on topic, well, it is not about programming etc. It is not a corporate IT support issue. If 'dropbox exists as a tag and this question is similar to other questions, why does it fail? maybe I have missed the reason listed in those links for why it is 'off-topic'?

Comment: @DavidPostill, ok, I am surprised given the number of **DROPBOX** tagged questions, and this is no different essentially, and given the fact that this is not a 'web service' since there is a **program installed** on my computer for the interface.

Comment: Fair enough. Close vote removed. BTW have you tried contacting spideroak support?

Comment: @DavidPostill, cheers, I have tried contacting them. And it is not an issue I have found in the troubleshooting section of the help. If I get an answer from them I will post it here for others that might encounter the same problem I am experiencing.

Comment: I suggest contacting SpiderOak support for assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a response from `spideroak`, my understanding now is:

> If the file hierarchy on the OS is affected in any way, it can affect the way SpiderOak views the files; eg. changing name results in a changed file path to the folders it examines for backup. The .config file is even associated to the path of the username, so if the file changes or the path it loses the information about the identity and reprompts for the signin and the device name. After signing in, **there is a button MORE OPTIONS**, and allows you to select from one of the pre-existing device names to *reinstall* the device on the same computer and puts them back into the same place :)  but if the locations have changed it will be assumed that those files/directories were deleted and put into the bin folder. There for a install new device option is recommended for safety.

I reinstalled the existing device and all is good.